# How to achieve fluency in 1 month

Tags: self-learning

I've been practicing English for 5 months because I have to go abroad for some work and for that I want to achieve fluency in English. I can understand what somebody is saying in English, but when I try to speak, I forget words, or words don't come to my mind. I know grammar well, but I do lack even in that while speaking.
Now I only have 1 month left.
Any suggestions you would like to give me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really unlikely to reach fluency in one month. However, you can still improve.

Since you are after verbal fluency, listen and speak as much as possible. Also, continue your current language learning strategies to the extent you can.

One exercise you can do is that you can think about what you would want to say in some situation and then formulate that in English, mentally. (For bonus points also pronounce it.) Like: what if my next meeting at work/talking with a librarian/etc. happened in English? What would I say? This way you can find out holes in your language skills by noticing what is hard for you to formulate in the language.

Also, when reading, try to pronounce the words (silently and mentally, or maybe even read out loud if that is feasible).

Finally, successful communication does not require fluency. It will come when you have to use the language all the time.

Comment: Unlikely no. It is impossible. Why not just say it?

Comment: I do not know the person, their background, their skills, and so on. I find "really unlikely" to be strong enough. In particular, I also forget words, but I still manage to express myself fairly fluently in English.

Comment: You already know English, apparently the OP does not know as much as you. Fluency in one month is a pipe dream. Even in six. We can't see who closed the question here. I wonder why?

Comment: (I can see who closed the question. No conspiracy there. Moderator action and reputation privileges maybe.)

Comment: Tommi, all other sites have a greyed out term: Close. This site does not. It only has: share follow edit flag. Is that because I don't have enough points? Or does it show up like that for you too?

Comment: I seem to be able to cast close votes (not testing without a reason, but the button is there). The reputation requirements are here: https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/privileges . They are site-specific.

Comment: Yes, I understand they are site specific. But is the button user specific?  Since I have lots of points on most sites, I have never seen the button not be there for close. OK, I just checked on another site where I don't have a lot of points, same thing.